# Google Maps Cluster v3 - Cannot Style Label text

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I got the following code:

```
var options = {
  styles: [
      {

          url: 'assets/images/marker/m1.png',
          height: 37,
          width: 25,
          anchorText:[0,-150],
      },
      {

          url: 'assets/images/marker/m2.png',
          height: 37,
          width: 25,
          anchorText:[0,-150],
      },
      {

          url: 'assets/images/marker/m3.png',
          height: 37,
          width: 25,
          anchorText:[0,-150],
      },
      {

          url: 'assets/images/marker/m4.png',
          height: 37,
          width: 25,
          anchorText:[0,-150],
      },
      {

          url: 'assets/images/marker/m5.png',
          height: 37,
          width: 25,
          anchorText:[0,-150],
      }
  ],
  maxZoom: 10
};
```

I read that anchorText can move the number inside the cluster in x or y directions (in pixel) but somehow It doesn't.

It looks like this:
[image]

Something changed again in the API for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [this MarkerClusterer library](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclusterer), the name of the style property that sets the anchor position of the label text is `anchor` and not `anchorText`.

Take a look at [this source code comment](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js#L58) about the supported options.

> 'anchor': (Array) The anchor position of the label text.

Comment: still the same. :/ Any other Ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: I was playing around with the anchor values and it seems like negative values don't work. It looks like values 19 -> 1 shift the title to the left/up and 21 -> ~49 shift the title to the right/down. These values depend on your width and height.

Comment: Take a look at [this code](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js#L1228-L1242). It checks `this.anchor_[0] > 0` and `this.anchor_[1] > 0` so negative values don't work. It also checks `this.anchor_[0] < this.height_` and `this.anchor_[1] < this.width_` so your values also have to be smaller than the height and width of your icon.